# Do we have to use robot framework to send a message to IoT hub?

Tags: azure-automation

I want to use the robot framework for run automation testing. My scenario is set connect string (HostName=xxx) and send a message to IoT hub and verify data in database after sent message. Anyone help me? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could make easily a RFW compatible wrapper library on azure-iot-hub python library. I made the same too with azure-servicebus python library to communicate through service bus. Using directly the API Rest with Restinstance or RequestsLibrary is another option. But for now I dont know specialized and maintained keywords for this.

Comment: I forget robotframework-mqttlibrary keywords solution if you want to simulate how the device send a message to IoT hub. I don't understand your use case in details.